# Ajax Timed Event Redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

Im trying to setup a redirect for a chat script. If the chat goes unanswered after x amount of time the page will redirect.

I posted a question here yesterday regarding the same thing, but at the time knowing little in regards to JS I was trying to mix php with js. I have changed tactics.

Here is what I got thus far:

```
function opCheck()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else
{
alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{

opCheck();                          
        //  alert('working2');                      
}
}
opjoined = "newchattimer.php";
xmlhttp.open("GET",opjoined,true);
xmlhttp.send(null); 
}

function opResult()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else
{
alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
 //alert('state = 4');
var op = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
ajaxurl = "ajaxfiles/opAnswer_12.txt";
xmlhttp.open("GET",ajaxurl,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

setTimeout(function() {
opCheck();
opResult();
//alert(op);
if (op == 'n') window.location.replace("chatnoop.php");
 }, 3000);
```

It creates the text file properly but ultimately no redirect. I used the chrome deveolpers tool and no errors. I also tried to `alert(op);` to see if the result is being grabbed, but I get no alert.

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had taken the time to indent your code, you'd see that `var op` is declared inside the scope of the `onreadystatechange` function, which is both out of scope and asynchronous.

```
function opResult() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            var op = xmlhttp.responseText; //declared here
        }
    }
    ajaxurl = "ajaxfiles/opAnswer_12.txt";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", ajaxurl, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

setTimeout(function () {
    opCheck();
    opResult();
    // op is out of scope here
    if (op == 'n') window.location.replace("chatnoop.php");
}, 3000);
```

Since timeouts aren't generally the way to handle async functions, and doing ajax request when all you intend to do when it finishes is to redirect anyway is'nt really neccessary, you could just do a regular form submit, which will redirect all by itself, or move the redirecting inside the right scope!

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if(xmlhttp.responseText == 'n') window.location.href = 'chatnoop.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: It runs some php to check the DB to see if an operator accepted the chat request. If operator has joined the chat then no redirect. So its a dynamic situation. I thought that ajax would be the best way.

Comment: Then you'd either have to add a success callback of some sorts, or just stick the redirect inside the right scope. Added some code above.

Comment: Thank you so much, with your help it actually made sense! It works!

Answer (score 0):

You may find what you want here http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php but basically i don't think that `window.location.replace("chatnoop.php");` is correct. You should consider using JQuery to manage all the Ajax stuff in addition, but it should work like you've done anyway